# How to merge lists in R and add certain columns together where there are duplicates?

Tags: r, merge, addition

I'm trying to combine two lists of different lengths where certain columns get added together and there are no duplicates, I can merge the two but it creates two different columns for each header. example: per.cov becomes per.cov.x and per.cov.y. I need to have those two added instead of creating different columns. Here is a shortened version of the data:

```
> MPS_T1
      spp per.cov native nnative nn.state
1   ACMIO       2      2       0        0
2   BRCA5      22     22       0        0
3   CACA9       4      0       4        4
4   COPA3       2      0       2        0

> MPS_T2
           spp per.cov native nnative nn.state
1        ACMIO       4      4       0        0
2        BRCA5       4      4       0        0
3        CACA9       2      0       2        2
4        CEAR4       2      2       0        0
```

Here is the code I am using with the current output

```
MPS <- merge(MPS_T1, MPS_T2, by = "spp", all = TRUE)
```

Current output:

```
> MPS
           spp per.cov.x native.x nnative.x nn.state.x per.cov.y native.y nnative.y
1        ACMIO         2        2         0          0         4        4         0
2        BRCA5        22       22         0          0         4        4         0
3        CACA9         4        0         4          4         2        0         2
4        CEAR4        NA       NA        NA         NA         2        2         0
5        COPA3         2        0         2          0        NA       NA        NA

   nn.state.y
1           0
2           0
3           2
4           0
5           0
6          NA
```

Desired output:
The numeric values in the columns with the same name (per.cov, native, nnative, nn.state) are added together. Any characters in column "spp" are just added to the list. Note that CEAR4 and COPA3 are not on both lists but are added to the bottom and there are no N/A's. (I guess the N/A's would have to equal 0 for this to work?).

```
 > MPS
               spp per.cov   native   nnative   nn.state
    1        ACMIO       6        6         0          0
    3        BRCA5      26       26         0          0
    4        CACA9       6        0         6          6
    5        CEAR4       2        2         0          0
    6        COPA3       2        0         2          0
```

I'm very new to this and could not find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use `aggregate`.

- Use `rbind` to combine the two dataframes
- Summarize the data in all columns using `spp` as the grouping variable `. ~ spp` and `sum` as the function by which to summarize

```
aggregate(. ~ spp, rbind(MPS_T1, MPS_T2), sum)

#----
    spp per.cov native nnative nn.state
1 ACMIO       6      6       0        0
2 BRCA5      26     26       0        0
3 CACA9       6      0       6        6
4 CEAR4       2      2       0        0
5 COPA3       2      0       2        0
```

---

The `dplyr` equivalent

```
library(dplyr)

MPS_T1 %>%
  bind_rows(MPS_T2) %>%
  group_by(spp) %>%
  summarize_all(sum)
```

---

Data

```
MPS_T1 <- read.table(text = "
     spp per.cov native nnative nn.state
1   ACMIO       2      2       0        0
2   BRCA5      22     22       0        0
3   CACA9       4      0       4        4
4   COPA3       2      0       2        0
")          

MPS_T2 <- read.table(text = "
           spp per.cov native nnative nn.state
1        ACMIO       4      4       0        0
2        BRCA5       4      4       0        0
3        CACA9       2      0       2        2
4        CEAR4       2      2       0        0
")
```